# How to make python selenium close browser once title loaded?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The task is to check all titles on many web pages are correct, I tried to make it fast via close the browser once title is loaded, but did not get the time down. Is selenium always loading all, i.e. until `</html>?`

I would like to have something like,

```
        driver.get('webpage_url')
        #t = EC.title_is('title_string')
        if driver.title:
                driver.close()
```

Comment: Yes, the `driver.get()` command causes selenium to wait for the entire page to be rendered in the target browser. It might be quite a bit lighter weight (and much faster) to use the `request` module because is doesn't start a browser instance if all you're checking is the page title...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using an Explicit Wait with an Excpected Condition.  Once the page is loaded, it will wait up to an additional 10 seconds for the title to match "Example Domain", then close the browser.  It polls the DOM while waiting... and will raise a `TimeoutException` after 10 secs if the title does not match yet.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webriver.Chrome()
driver.get(https://example.com)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.title_is("Example Domain"))
driver.close()
```